# Need to prevent ASP.NET FileUpload filenames with invalid characters

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, file-upload

I have an legacy ASP.NET WebForms application with a page that has a FileUpload control on it to upload images. I need to enforce a validation rule that says the filename must contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores (spaces are not allowed).

I've tried a couple of different techniques including a RegularExpressionValidator associated with the FileUpload. That doesn't work although I think my regular expression isn't correct. I've tried different permutations and the last I tried was:

```
^[\w]+\.[\w]+$
```

The second was to use a CustomValidator and on the server side, either using a regular expression or scanning the filename, character by character. The custom validator approach was my first attempt, but I set the breakpoint in the validator's event handler (as specified by the OnServerValidate property) and the breakpoint was never hit.

I would prefer to use the RegularExpressionValidator since it provides client-side and server-side validation and doesn't require any code to be written, however, it seems to me that this type of validator doesn't work with a FileUpload control. Am I doing something wrong, or is this just not possible? I also have a RequiredFieldValidator associated with the FileUpload and that works fine.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuCustomerLogo" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCustomerLogo" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fuCustomerLogo" ErrorMessage="Customer Logo is required" Text="*" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revCustomerLogo" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fuCustomerLogo" ErrorMessage="Customer Logo FileName must contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores" Text="*" ValidationExpression="^[\w]+\.[\w]+$" />
```

Comment: Try a different regex like  ^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+$ . You may need to tweak it.

Comment: @Hakunamatata, I tried this using that regular expression and it seems to reject any file name I select. I've also tried ^([A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]|_|-|\.|\s)+$ but that doesn't work either. Any other ideas? I'm not good at regular expressions.

Comment: This regular expression works in a unit test: ^[A-Za-z0-9_.]{1,}$

However, when I plug it into the ValidationExpression property of the RequiredFieldValidator, it doesn't work. Anything and everything fails to pass validation. Does anyone know of a case where someone has tried doing this and it actually worked? I am starting to think that there is no way to do this and I'll have to resort to checking the validity of the filename on a postback.